# Twitter API - How to get User Details like First Name, Last Name and Email Address from access_token

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

My services are calling Twitter APIs after we get access_token (when the user logs in to an application using Twitter) from Twitter as an Identity Provider.

Questions is: Is there any single API which gives User details (Name, Email) by passing access_token ?

Whatever I understoon from Twitter Docs are: 
 1. We need to call [GET account/verify_credentials](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials) by passing access_token - we will get user_id
 2. Again we will need to call [GET users/show](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show)  which will take user_id as input and will provide us User Details (which have UserName, but not EMAIL)

Please help me identify API which can take Access_token and provide User details like Name and Email ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you will get only those properties which a user object contain
=>for more info visit: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object.html
**And In Twitter's eyes, accounts are not really tied to a real email like Facebook or Google are and is less firmly attached to a real-world identity. Email is seen more as a formality to Twitter and accounts are more directly tied to their username.**

Comment: How to get this User Object using Access_token ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate consumerKey and clientSecret key by logging in into twitter(developer) account. And have to use those like below Syntax could be differ

'twitterAuth' : {
        'consumerKey'       : 'your-consumer-key-here',
        'consumerSecret'    : 'your-client-secret-here',
        'callbackURL'       : 'http://localhost:8080/auth/twitter/callback'
    },

If you are using node.js it could be useful to you
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-twitter

Comment: how to call it using postman ? Do you know syntax and how to pass these params ?